# Dynamic Links not working on iOS cordova app

Tags: objective-c, cordova, cordova-plugins, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I have added the `cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks` plugin to my project.

However, deep-links do not persist after the app installation. I tried it in 2 separate apps, and this is the error I'm getting:

```
---- Firebase Dynamic Links diagnostic output start ----
Firebase Dynamic Links framework version 3.0.1
System information: OS iOS, OS version 11.2.6, model iPhone
Current date 2018-08-06 03:47:11 +0000
Device locale en-CH (raw en_CH), timezone Europe/Zurich
ERROR: UIApplication delegate <AppDelegate: 0x1c4225240> does not implements selector application:openURL:options:. FDL depends on this implementation to retrieve pending dynamic link.
    AppID Prefix: xxx, Team ID: xxx, AppId Prefix equal to Team ID: YES
performDiagnostic detected 1 ERROR.
---- Firebase Dynamic Links diagnostic output end ----
```

I have also tried a fork that seems to have some fixes in it, but it didn't work either: https://github.com/Chuckv01/cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks

Judging from the error message, it looks like something is not implemented right. However, the plugin author said that it did work for him.

I am not a native developer, but is the `application:openURL:options:` selector correctly implemented? I can't find it in the code, but maybe there is some magic going on that I don't understand or maybe it's done in the Firebase SDK itself.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It does look like that method is missing. The repo linked supports the right parameters for a universal link based deep link, but looks like it is missing the older openUrl method for older iOS versions, and post-install deeplinking.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Would you happen to know where I can put that `application:openURL:options` handler within the plugin?

Comment: https://github.com/Chuckv01/cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks/blob/master/src/ios/AppDelegate%2BFirebaseDynamicLinksPlugin.m in the app delegate category